# How to redirect to form with errors if not valid in Symfony2?

Tags: validation, symfony

I don't know how to redirect errors to a form if it's not valid with Symfony2?

So I use the Assert in my entity like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $title;
```

And this is my createAction method :

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();

    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($task);
            $em->flush();
        }

        // What should I do here if the form is not valid

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'The task has been added successfully!');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crm_tasks'));
    }

    return $this->render('LanCrmBundle:Task:create.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

What should I do to return errors to the form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should include the FlashBag() and return statement **inside** the if($form->isValid) condition.

```
 if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'The task has been added successfully!');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crm_tasks'));
 }
```

If not valid, the user will be redirected to the form, displaying the error if Symfony catched it.

Comment: this doesnt answer how to redirect after a failed submission with passing the error. Say you want to upload an image to a separate endpoint, image too big -> redirect back to page with all the configuration AND the error.